# Cant build project because of cached Dependencies (java)

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to package my project to a jar, whenever I try this it fails to compile because of old cached dependencies I dont use anymore.

> Could not resolve dependencies for project at.htl:testmonitoring-client:jar:1.18.47: Failed to collect dependencies [old dependencies] in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: Just simply try to delete in $HOME/.m2/repository/... ?

Comment: This isn't related to git, and is only related to java in the sense that Maven is primarily a java-based tool; I'd suggest updating the tags

Comment: See if `mvn -U package` (or whatever your goal is) helps.  The `-U` option, though documented to mean "update snapshots", also forces a general recheck of metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using the dependencies, then you should remove them from the pom.  If the dependency is not in the pom, then (most of the time) Maven won't try to resolve them and the build won't fail.

If you've removed them from the pom but maven is still trying to resolve them, then it may mean that something is using them transitively.  You can check on that with `mvn dependency:tree`

If for whatever reason the build needs to resolve them, then the simplest thing is to remove the "cached failures" from your local repo.  The easiest thing to do is remove the entire ~/.m2/repository directory (and all subdirectories and content thereof), which is probably safe as maven will reconstruct it from the remote. The only problem would be if you have/need artifacts in the local repo that don't exist on any remote.  If that's not the case, you won't lose anything by doing it, though it will make the next build take longer as it must download everything again.

If you can't remove the entire local repo, then you could still track down the specific artifacts causing the problem.  For example, if you have a problem with an artifact groupId=com.some.comapny artifactId=someArtifact, version=1.0.0 then you could remove ~/.m2/repository/com/some/company/someArtifact/1.0.0 (and all content thereof).

Note that this assumes Maven will be able to resolve the dependencies from the configured remote(s).  If they aren't available in the remotes you've configured, then you may have to resolve that (either by adding them to your local repo manager, by adding public repos that do have the artifacts, etc.).

Comment: thank you for the fast answer :)
I deleted all in my C:\Users\{username}\.m2 folder but get still the same error.
I dont understand how this can happen because the missing dependencies are not in the repository folder.

Comment: You  may still have gotten errors, but if your local repo were removed then you could not get the *same* error (at least not on the very next run); with no local repo there are no cached failures. One problem with the Maven client IMO is that if you've been getting one error and you start getting a different error, if you skim the output it often gives the impression it's the same error (bc the error messages are long and all start out the same).  So I can think of three possibilities:

Comment: 1) It's possible that the next run actually gave a *different* error saying that the artifact couldn't be resolved.  This could mean that you don't have the necessary remotes configured.  Note that a re-run after you get that error *would* take you back to the "failure to fetch was cached" error.  You might be able to learn what repo(s) you need by searching for the artifact at http://mvnrepository.com/ ...

Comment: 2) When you deleted your .m2 directory, you may have removed configuration information that you needed (such as remote repo configurations).  This is why I said to delete the *repository* under .m2, not the .m2 directory (see also my comment on Mayank Sharma's answer).  That would lead you back to the first problem.  The most likely situation would be if you had a local repo manager (like Nexus or Artifactory) configured in settings.xml ...

Comment: 3) Though I think this is *much* less likely, it's possible that your local Maven configuration is non-standard, and that your repo is at a different path (not ~/.m2/repository).  You can double-check this with `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository `

Comment: But it also sounds like you haven't looked into the other side of the issue I mentioned: if you're really not using the artifact, you should tell Maven that it doesn't have to resolve it.  Before getting too lost on other investigations, I'd make sure you don't have unneeded dependencies in the pom and check the dependency tree to see if there's a clear reason this artifact is being resolved in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

go to home directory and delete .m2 (hidden directory) folder and  update project and run it.

Comment: Deleting the entire .m2 directory is dangerous advice; the repository isn't the only thing that might be there.